# Is it safe to share half of the private key in WIF format?

Tags: security, private-key, wallet-recovery, cryptography, wallet-security

Assuming I would generate my keys on https://www.bitaddress.org.

Is it safe to share the following four pieces of data?

```
One half of the private key.
The public key.
An SHA512 hash of the private key.
An SHA512 hash of the public key.
```

By private key I mean the string representation as a 52-digit hexadecimal number. One half of the private key would be the first 1 to 26 characters of this string.

Can I assume that the person receiving this information will not be able to reconstruct the private keys by intelligently combining this information or by running an attack like a brute-force-attack?

Comment: Why would you want to share this data in the first place?

Comment: This question is about secret sharing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing . Advantages of these methods can be found on wikipedia.

Comment: Just use Shamir's Secret Sharing. Trying to invent your own cryptographic scheme is almost always a terrible idea.

Comment: @Vojtěch Strnad : Thank you for your comment. I have been thinking a long time about it and I also tried out the ssss-split and ssss-combine packages. Then I was wondering wheather these algorithms are standardized and found this post: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83924 The author says: "Whatever you use, you'd better keep around its source code so that it may be recompiled or at least ported on the machine you will have twenty years from now.". As I am not yet convinced I would love to also get an answer to my original post.

Comment: You should link to your related question which has an answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109752/in-bitcoin-given-half-the-52-character-private-key-in-wif-format-is-it-possibl

Comment: How would I formulate that this answer was not helpful for me from a practical standpoint without risking to get this question deleted?